# unable to execute 'webdriver-manager update' for protractor

Tags: node.js, proxy, protractor, firewall, webdriver-manager

When i tried to installing protractor in my office PC, I am getting stuck at the step 'webdriver-manager update' in the command terminal.I did not face this obstacle when I tried the command in my personal laptop.The error thrown is as below,

> C:\Users\616356>webdriver-manager update
>       [10:45:09] I/config_source - curl -o C:\Users\616356\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\standalone-response.xml
>   https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
>       [10:45:09] I/config_source - curl -o C:\Users\616356\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml
>   https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
>       [10:45:09] I/config_source - curl -o C:\Users\616356\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\gecko-response.json
>   https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
>       events.js:165
>             throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>             ^
>
> ```
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.217.166.112:443
>     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14)
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>     at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\616356\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\request\request.js:881:8)
>     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:185:15)
>     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:395:9)
>     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:180:13)
>     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
> ```

I think the issue might be regarding some firewall or proxy problem.I tried adding 172.217.166.112 in the proxy exceptions, it didn't work.I just don't know how to resolve this issue.Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: run your console as a administrator

Comment: If your office PC access public network requires proxy, you need to specify option `--proxy` as `webdriver-manager update --proxy <proxy url>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example like this
webdriver-manager update --proxy http://TPESproxy.galileo.corp.lcl:8980